# How do I decrypt an encrypted input?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, sha256

So I tried this code from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) about openssl_encrypt. It does encrypt the id but it does not decrypt the value once I submit the form.

```
<?php

$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $c = base64_decode($_POST['id']);
        $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
        $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
        $id = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
        var_dump(hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac));
        if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac))// timing attack safe comparison
        {
            header("location: radio.php?value=$id");
        }
        
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <?php
        $id = 1; 
        $ids = openssl_encrypt($id, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ids, $key, $as_binary=true);
        $newid = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ids);
        echo '<input type="text" name="id" value='.$newid.'>';
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I want the value to show in the URL but even if I use var_dump(), it doesn't output anything.

Comment: To decrypt you must use the exact same key that was used to encrypt. You can't generate a random key and expect it to decrypt anything.

Comment: I am so sorry. I was so zoned out while programming this that I didn't even noticed that. Thank you so much.